# Create Model relationship with just an ID rather than full Model?

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible to just assign the ID to the owning side of a relationship rather than querying the DB, loading the record and assigning it?

Something similar to Doctrines `_getReference()`

- http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#_getReference
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308576/1982031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's actually the way to do it, assign the id to the owning record:

```
$record = new Cocktails_CocktailRecord;
$record->authorId = 10;
$record->title = "Gin Tonic";
$record->save();
```

When getting the record from the db, the record is turned into a model, at this point, records and models are only dealing with authorId, not the whole record. Your model will then have to define a getAuthor() method that will get the author user for you:

```
public function getAuthor()
{
    if ($this->authorId) {
        return craft()->users->getUserById($this->authorId);
    }
}
```

This way your model only loads the relationship when you actually use it:

```
$model->getAuthor();
```

Comment: Yeah setting the id directly works. I thought it didn't when I first tried it but it does.